# C# MVC3 - LINQ select and foreach loop in Razor, what am I missing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following Action in Controller:

```
public ViewResult Index()
{        
    //select
    var query = (from u in db.UserSets
                 join f in db.FriendRequestsSets on u.ID equals f.FriendID
                 orderby u.ID
                 select new {Id = u.ID, Nickname = u.Nickname}).AsEnumerable();

    ViewBag.FriendRequests = query;
    return View(this.UserColl());
}
```

The following foreach in my Razor view:

```
<ul>
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.FriendRequests)
{
    <li>@item.Nickname</li>
}
</ul>
```

And the following error:

```
*'object' does not contain a definition for 'Nickname'*
```

What am I missing in my code?

Comment: When I try to display the page in my browser

Comment: Is it a compiler error or a runtime error? (Do you see a stack trace?)

Comment: I see the error in the Razor view, inside foreach... not a stack trace

Comment: So it's a compiler error.  That shouldn't happen.  Try changing `var` to `dynamic`.

Comment: That's really strange.  I have no idea what's wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ViewBag is of type object, not an Enumerable!

What you can do, is to have a class as follow:

```
Class User{
  public int Id;
  public string Nickname;
  }
```

then populate an list of User class as bellow:

```
var query = (from u in db.UserSets
             join f in db.FriendRequestsSets on u.ID equals f.FriendID
             orderby u.ID
             select new User{Id = u.ID, Nickname = u.Nickname}).ToList();
```

and at last in your view do this:

```
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.FriendRequests as List<User> )
    {
      <li>@item.Nickname</li>
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi CjCoax, thank you for your answer. I placed the class inside the controller, inside the View I can't find this User class, I am missing any code line inside the view? The new error is The type or namespace name 'User' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Hi Rubia, Suppose that your controller namespace is RubiaApplication.Controllers (and the User class is within this namespace, not inside the Controller class itself), you need to add this at the top of your view: @using RubiaApplication.Controllers (it imports the namespace which the User class resides in)